# Make empty :after occupy it's predecessors width and height

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm using an `:after` on a div to add an overlay background (in my case I can't just add it as second one to original div)

And I'm trying to force it to occupy whole width and height of its "predecessor" div, tried width and height at 100% as well as inherit, but nothing works, content of `:after` element is empty ("") but it has a background image that needs to be displayed.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/96VfF/ (Here is js fiddle)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and post your code here? Thanks.

Comment: the default `display` of pseudo-element is `inline`, you have to set `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to be able to set the `width` and `height`.

Comment: @KingKing oh true, you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: No it's good to know that fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning.

[**Sample Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8534N/).

```
div {
   padding: 30px; 
   position: relative;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: when using `position:absolute` or `fixed`, we don't need to specify `display:block`, looks like it will be block implicitly. Here you can see without using `display:block`, its computed style `display` will be automatically changed to `block` (when `position:absolute`).http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/8534N/1/